# Can't seem to get value from angular binding control in ng-change event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a simple Angular/Ionic page:

```
<ion-view ng-controller="HomeController">
    <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
        <ion-toggle ng-model="shareLoc" ng-change="shareLocChange()" toggle-class="toggle-stable">Share location</ion-toggle>
       Current value: {{shareLoc}}
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

In the controller I print the value of the checkbox when the value is changed:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller("HomeController", function ($scope) {
    console.log('HomeController');
    $scope.shareLoc = false;
    $scope.shareLocChange = function() {
        console.log($scope.shareLoc);
    };
});
```

But it doesn't work! I can bind to it in other HTML fields (as shown above) but for some reason whenever I access it in code it's returning false (or whatever I set it to in the controller initialisation). Have I ended up with the wrong `$scope` or something?!

Example at http://codepen.io/pugwonk/pen/OVymYv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `ion-view` creates an isolated scope, so if you pass a primitive parameter it's gonna copy it by value, and when it changes - the original will stay the same.

On the other hand - if you pass an object as the parameter, both scopes will be able to use the same copy.

You can see the different scope IDs and the passing of an object [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJjwzB).

Comment: Great sleuthing, thank you. And, indeed, moving the scope down to the ion-content makes it work great. I had no idea that different elements had different types of scope - or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

So, I'm actually somewhat puzzled by this, however passing the value of your model through your function fixes your problem.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/pJjPMB?editors=101)

```
ng-change="shareLocChange(shareLoc)" 

$scope.shareLocChange = function(shareLoc) {
  console.log(shareLoc);
};
```

Comment: I noticed that too and it's a good workaround - unfortunately in the rest of my code I pop a 'confirm' dialog box and need to be able to set the value back to its previous setting, so I do need the actual binding to get passed. :(